# GMLib Delphi, Trying to create a proof of concept application, Map, GeoCode, Markers

Tags: delphi, geocode, gmlib

I have the basic part of the app/map working/displaying. But when I try to geocode multiple addresses and then display the markers, it only shows me the last address. Only the last address will show on the map.

```
  GMGeoCode1.Geocode('address 1 anytown st');
  GMGeoCode1.Geocode('address 2 anytown st');
    for I := 0 to GMGeoCode1.Count - 1 do
    begin
    GMGeoCode1.Marker.Add(GMGeoCode1.GeoResult [i] .Geometry.Location.Lat,
           GMGeoCode1.GeoResult [i] .Geometry.Location.Lng,
           GMGeoCode1.GeoResult [i] .FormatedAddr);
         GMGeoCode1.Marker.Items [i] .MarkerType := mtStyledMarker;
    end;
```

Comment: I got this part working by unsetting the property of the GMGeoCode for the Marker property.  Now i am trying to add more than the basic 10 addresses to the gecode process. I went and applied for an apikey (server and browser) but neither of these keys makes a difference in the test project i have created. How can i get more than 10 addresses to geocode an place a marker for them on a map?

Answer (score 1):

The TGMGeoCode component can only store one geocoding. The GeoResult array is because a geocoding can return more than one result.
For example, if you geocodes Toledo defining USA like region, you will get 4 results
1.- Toledo, Ohio
2.- Toledo, Oregon
3.- Toledo, Iowa
4.- Toledo, Washington

an the GeoResult will have 4 entries, one for each of the results.

If you want store all geocodifications, you need to add results to the TGMMarker every geocodification

Comment: Thanks that got me going.